# Retrieve 2 S3 objects and their content using only 1 request [C# AWSSDK]

Tags: c#, amazon-s3, .net-core, aws-sdk

I have the following file S3 bucket:

"BucketName"

- folder1

  - usa

    - file1.zip
    - file2.zip
  - canada

    - file1.zip
    - file2.zip

Is there a way I can retrieve the content (i.e. list the keys) from the "*BucketName/folder1/*" path that will give me both the `**usa**` and `**canada**` object's files in 1 request to S3.

Currently, I have the following code that makes 2 requests to S3 which I am trying to avoid to retrieve all of the files for each of the 2 countries:

```
public List<string> GetShapefiles(string country)
{

    var s3Request = new ListObjectsV2Request
    {
        BucketName = BucketName,
        Delimiter = "/"
    };

    if (country == "US")
    {
        s3Request.Prefix = "BucketName/folder1/usa/";

        return GetShapeFileList(s3Request);
    }

    else if (country == "Canada")
    {
        s3Request.Prefix = "BucketName/folder1/canada/";

        return GetShapeFileList(s3Request);
    }

}

    private List<string> GetShapeFileList(ListObjectsV2Request request)
{
    var result = new List<string>();
    ListObjectsV2Response response;

        do
        {
            response = S3_CLIENT.ListObjectsV2Async(request).Result;

            foreach (var file in response.S3Objects.Where(f => f.Key.LastIndexOf('/') != f.Key.Length - 1))
            {
                result.Add(file.Key);
            }

            request.ContinuationToken = response.NextContinuationToken;
        } while (response.IsTruncated);

        return result;
}
```

So ideally, I would like to make only 1 request that gives me all of the zip files for both usa and Canada like so:

```
/usa/file1.zip
/usa/file2.zip
/canada/file1.zip
/canada/file2.zip
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Amazon S3 doesn't support retrieving multiple ranges of data per GET
> request.
>     -    https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/GettingObjectsUsingAPIs.html

Your best bet is to continue what you're doing - iterating through your objects and retrieving each. This can be done either simultaneously or asynchronously - I'd recommend fetching each object from S3 in parallel. Best of luck!

Comment: Thank you for your comment. It does help to know that this is not supported.