# how to use Amazon S3 connector in wso2 ei 6.6 to get all the objects in particular subfolder?

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I have multiple csv files in object 'bbb' which is in bucket 'aaa'.
I am able to download single file as shown below using the Amazon S3 connector with 'getObject' functionality
local entry looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<localEntry key="AMAZON_S3_CONNECTION_1" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <amazons3.init>
        <awsAccessKeyId>**</awsAccessKeyId>
        <name>AMAZON_S3_CONNECTION_1</name>
        <region>**</region>
        <connectionType>amazons3</connectionType>
        <awsSecretAccessKey>**</awsSecretAccessKey>
    </amazons3.init>
</localEntry>
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy name="AmazonConnectivity" startOnLoad="true" transports="http https vfs" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <target>
        <inSequence>
            <log level="full">
                <property name="log" value="====S3 to Local===="/>
            </log>
            <amazons3.getObject configKey="AMAZON_S3_CONNECTION_1">
                <bucketName>aaa</bucketName>
                <objectKey>bbb/xyz.csv</objectKey>
            </amazons3.getObject>
            <log level="full">
                <property name="log" value="====After Amazon S3 Init===="/>
            </log>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence/>
        <faultSequence/>
    </target>
    <parameter name="transport.PollInterval">5</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.vfs.FileURI">vfs:file:///C:/amazon-s3</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.vfs.ContentType">text/plain</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.vfs.ActionAfterProcess">MOVE</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.vfs.MoveAfterFailure">vfs:file:///C:/failure</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.vfs.ActionAfterFailure">MOVE</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.vfs.FileNamePattern">.*.rdy</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.vfs.MoveAfterProcess">vfs:file:///C:/out</parameter>
</proxy>
```

but now I want to bulk download all the files in object 'bbb'. Can someone help me with it.
I am using Amazon S3 connector -Version 2.0.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to refer to WSO2 S3 Connector Doc [here](https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/7.0.0/micro-integrator/references/connectors/amazons3-connector/amazons3-connector-reference/) for reference.

However, an example use case of the ***getObjectsInBucket*** that can be used for this scenario is below.

You can set the value in `<prefix></prefix>` for the targeted sub-folder you want to list.

Sample Request to List:

```
<getObjectsInBucket>
    <accessKeyId>ACCESS_KEY</accessKeyId>
    <secretAccessKey>ACCESS_SECRET</secretAccessKey>
    <region>REGION</region>
    <delimiter>DELIMITER</delimiter>
    <encodingType>ENCODING_TYPE</encodingType>
    <methodType>GET</methodType>
    <bucketName>aaa</bucketName>
    <bucketUrl>BUCKET_URL</bucketUrl>
    <host>HOST_URL</host>
    <prefix>bbb</prefix>
</getObjectsInBucket>
```

Edit:

Sample Request to Download:

```
<getObject>
    <accessKeyId>AKIXXXXXHXQXXG5XX</accessKeyId>
    <secretAccessKey>qHXXBXXXXASYQc4oMCEOj+343HD82s</secretAccessKey>
    <methodType>GET</methodType>
    <contentType>application/xml</contentType>
    <region>us-east-2</region>
    <host>s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com</host>
    <bucketUrl>http://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/signv4test</bucketUrl>
    <bucketName>signv4test</bucketName>
    <isXAmzDate>true</isXAmzDate>
    <xAmzSecurityToken/>
    <contentMD5/>
    <objectName>Tree2.png</objectName>
    <rangeBytes/>
    <responseContentType/>
    <responseContentLanguage/>
    <responseExpires/>
    <responseCacheControl/>
    <responseContentDisposition/>
    <range/>
    <ifModifiedSince/>
    <ifUnmodifiedSince/>
    <ifMatch/>
    <ifNoneMatch/>
</getObject>
```

**However, downloading multiple object is not supported** as for the [AWS S3 Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_GetObject.html). There are suggested workarounds as similar to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63264005/retrieve-2-s3-objects-and-their-content-using-only-1-request-c-awssdk)

Comment: with this option-<getObjectsInBucket> the response is listing all the 50 files in 'bbb' but is there way to download all of them. or I have to use getObject after this download files one by one

Comment: @aditi21, Unfortunately, that is not directly supported from the end of AWS S3(https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_GetObject.html). That is why WSO2 AWS S3 Connector is also not supporting that. However, there are workarounds to achieve this. Kindly suggest you to refer these stack threads (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11420694/possible-to-get-multiple-object-from-amazon-s3-in-single-request, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63264005/retrieve-2-s3-objects-and-their-content-using-only-1-request-c-awssdk)

Comment: I already tried for one object, wanted to know if there is option for multiple download. thanks for the details explaination.